# How to traverse a file and extract words using their index?

Tags: text-processing, scripting

The given file must **not** be stored in variable and then traversed due to memory size restrictions:

Example:

```
var=$(cat FILE)
for i in $var
do
  echo $i
done
```

How do you traverse all strings in a file in the same way as the example above but extract each whitespace-separated directly from the file?

Example:

```
fileindex=1
totalfilecount=$(cat FILE | wc -w)
while (( ${fileindex} <= ${totalfilecount} ))
do
  onefilename= ??? missing command using fileindex
  ((fileindex+=1))
done
```

Is there a command that can view a file as an array and allow you to extract words using their index positions?

The idea is to process every word in the file as though the file were an array.

Input file example:

```
one two
three four
five six
```

Here is the scenario that requires the above funtionality:

- we have server_A and server_B
- server_A needs to connect to server_B via sftp (sftp only) and 'get' some files
- BOTH 'ls' or 'ls -l' commands in sftp can be using wild cards to filter specific files
- each file needs to be processed individually (for various reasons) on the fly
- the files cannot be copied as a group to server_B and then processed individually
- a list of files must first be created on server_A and then each file in that list is copied from server_B and processed one file at a time

Where is the problem?

The problem is how the 'ls' command can create a dual column list of words if the list is long thus not allowing simple processing as with 'ls -l' which always creates a single column list.

This leads us to my initial question, if such a solution exists.

Comment: @h3rrmiller `strings` won't do what is being asked here.

Comment: @h3rrmiller How does using `strings` allow extraction of individual strings as stated in the question?

Comment: @h3rrmiller You may wish to read the comments.

Comment: @ChrisDown you deleted your comment about the new lines...

Answer (score 2):

You can do this per word using `awk`, which should meet your memory requirements:

```
awk -v RS=\  '{
    # Do something with the word
    print
}' file
```

You can specify which string you want by using `NR`.

```
$ awk -v RS=\  'NR==2{print}' <<< 'foo bar baz'
bar
```

Comment: The idea is to process every string in the file as though the file were an array, without processing lines.

Comment: @AleksandarHadjikan Okay, edited.

Comment: This is very good. Is there a way to send an index to awk to specify which word to print out?

Comment: @AleksandarHadjikan Added it to my answer.

Comment: If I pass it a file (cat file | awk -v RS=\ 'NR==2{print}') that has 3 lines: "one two" , "three four" , "five six" it prints out "two" and then "three" on seperate lines.

Comment: @AleksandarHadjikan - Please describe more clearly the data input/output in your question. The way I read it, all data was on one line. How would you like to treat new lines? That's undefined behaviour in your question.

Comment: The input is a multiline (but not always multiline) text file containing words seperated by spaces, tabs, new lines, etc ... (like an entire book) I need to extract each word using an index in variable form and save that word in a variable to be processed.

Comment: @AleksandarHadjikan But are the words on new lines still within the same array? Do they extend the indices or create a new array? That is what I don't understand.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. The file consists of seperate lines and on each line there are words seperated by spaces or tabs. I added example input file text in my first question.

Comment: @AleksandarHadjikan - That still doesn't answer if they are in the same array or not...

Comment: We are talking about an 'ls' of a large directory that produces a mutli column output that is saved to a file.

Comment: @AleksandarHadjikan It really sounds like you are going about this the complete wrong way. It would be much better *not* to do that.

Comment: I updated my initial question with the specific scenario.

Answer (score 1):

When you say “strings” you mean “words”, right? Strings of characters separated by whitespace. And according to your examples, you want to access them sequentially.

You can do:

```
$ sed 's/[ \t]\+/\n/g' YOUR_FILE | while read -r word ; do PROCESS $word ; done
```

Example of use:

```
% echo word1 word2 > YOUR_FILE
% echo word3 word4 >> YOUR_FILE
% echo word5 word6 >> YOUR_FILE
% sed 's/[ \t]\+/\n/g' YOUR_FILE | while read -r word ; do echo _${word}_ ; done
_word1_
_word2_
_word3_
_word4_
_word5_
_word6_
```

Comment: Yes string=word. I tried your example however it did not work. I echo $word and it prints the entire file.

Comment: Works for me. See example. In what way do the contents of your file differ from lines of words separated by spaces?

Comment: Will break if the file contains backslashes.

Comment: I create three seperate lines with two words in each line.

Comment: @ChrisDown Yes, apparently `read` is the culprit. Fixed.

Comment: @AleksandarHadjikan The example does that now... Maybe you can post file and your modifications to the command, and we'll try to figure out why it fails.

Comment: I said file when I meant line. It is still printing line by line. "_one two_"

Comment: @angus - That's a slightly odd way to do it, `read -r` is what you want.

Comment: I run the command exactly as in your example using read or read -r and prints line by line: \_word1 word2\_

Comment: @ChrisDown Who knew? :) Thanks. @AleksandarHadjikan That's strange, I don't know what to make of it. Better use the `awk` version. As a last resort, try replacing `[ \t]\+` with `[ \t\xA0]\+`.